# How do i calculate days / weeks past from current date to DateTime mysql field

Tags: mysql, datetime

I have datatime field in mysql , im working with php .
how is the best way to calculate and present to the user how much time is past from current day to the time in the field ?
so it present me something like :

```
2 days ago ..
2 weeks ago ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the `DateDiff(CurrentTime, DatabaseTimeField)` function. It will return you the difference between two dates in `Days`. Then you can use that those days to present the difference to users.

e.g.

```
if(days <= 6)
 displays days
else
 display days%7 weeks
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use the SQL [DATEDIFF](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff) function to include in your SELECT statement the number of days that have passed. And then in php convert convert the days to weeks or month...

Something like:

```
SELECT DATADIFF(date, NOW()) AS daysPassed, ... FROM table
```

And in php:

```
$show //the string to display
$days = ... //get the daysPassed value from SQL
if($days > 6)
   $show = $days % 7 + " weeks ago";
else
   $show = $days + " days ago";
```

Comment: The if(days) can by in SQL itself also, using `WHEN... THEN` or `IF()`